# What is the more elegant way to remove all characters after specific character in the String object in Swift

Tags: swift

What is the more elegant way to remove all characters after specific character in the `String` object in Swift?

Suppose that I have the following string: `str.str` and I need to remove the `.str` from it. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
var str = "str.str"

if let dotRange = str.rangeOfString(".") {
    str.removeRange(dotRange.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
}
```

**Update**
In Swift 3 it is:

```
var str = "str.str"

if let dotRange = str.range(of: ".") {
  str.removeSubrange(dotRange.lowerBound..<str.endIndex)
}
```

Comment: Swift 3: if let dotRange = str.range(of: ".") {
            str.removeSubrange(dotRange.lowerBound..< str.endIndex)
        }

Answer (score 43):

Quite a compact way would be:

```
var str = "str.str"
str = str.componentsSeparatedByString(".")[0]
```

Another option you might be interested in, which works for your example 'str.str' but doesn't fit your specification is:

```
str = str.stringByDeletingPathExtension
// Returns a new string made by deleting the extension (if any, and only the last)
// from the `String`
```

Comment: 'stringByDeletingPathExtension' i think this one is deprecated

Comment: In Swift 4.2 use `str = str.components(separatedBy: (".")[0]`

Answer (score 41):

I think this is better approach:

Update with **Swift 4**:
(substring is now deprecated)

```
let smth = "element=value"

if let index = (smth.range(of: "=")?.upperBound)
{
  //prints "value"
  let afterEqualsTo = String(smth.suffix(from: index))

  //prints "element="
  let beforeEqualsToContainingSymbol = String(smth.prefix(upTo: index))
}

if let index = (smth.range(of: "=")?.lowerBound)
{
  //prints "=value"
  let afterEqualsToContainingSymbol = String(smth.suffix(from: index))

  //prints "element"
  let beforeEqualsTo = String(smth.prefix(upTo: index))
}
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 16):

This works in swift 5 and literally takes one line

```
textString = textString.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the solution i was after to get specific information from a filepath using 'separatedBy: "/"'

Answer (score 5):

#### Swift 5.1

```
/**
 * Splits a string at the first occurrence of a delimiter string
 * ## Examples:
 * splitAtFirst(str: "element=value", delimiter: "=") // "element", "value"
 */
public static func splitAtFirst(str: String, delimiter: String) -> (a: String, b: String)? {
   guard let upperIndex = (str.range(of: delimiter)?.upperBound), let lowerIndex = (str.range(of: delimiter)?.lowerBound) else { return nil }
   let firstPart: String = .init(str.prefix(upTo: lowerIndex))
   let lastPart: String = .init(str.suffix(from: upperIndex))
   return (firstPart, lastPart)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it would be best to use `prefix(while:)`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/prefix(while:)

Long syntax:

```
let greeting = "Hello, playground"
let prefix = greeting.prefix(while: { (character) -> Bool in
    return character != " "
})
```

Short syntax:

```
let greeting = "Hello, playground"
let prefix = greeting.prefix(while: { $0 != " " })
```

Output would be:

```
print(prefix) //This prints "Hello,"
```